# How to create a List with days of the first week of the month? (C#)

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, calendar, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to do it on this format?

```
public static int[,] Values
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean... at the moment you're creating a rectangular array, so that's not even a list. If you're effectively trying to create a table for a date picker, I'd expect there to be other date pickers already available in Xamarin.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am creating a calendar using a a Grid and Buttons,the rectangular arrray will do my 7 Columns (days) and 5 Rows (Weeks), but I want to get this 35 days using DateTime this way I'll have the right day on my first week instead of always starting with 1

Comment: So why do you want to do this rather than using a built-in control? I'd expect each platform to have a native picker, making your app more attractive. (As an aside, if you're doing a lot of date/time work, I'd personally - and very biasedly - recommend using my Noda Time project instead of DateTime.)

Comment: I will definitely have a look, thanks! I suppose you are talking about this (http://nodatime.org/)

Comment: Yup. There are nuget/Xamarin packages available.

Comment: And could you tell me how can I get this array with the 35 days using Noda Time?

For now I am doing something really basic a "Month view" in a Grid with 35 Buttons, all I need is to get the date range from my first week(first day) of the month until the last week (last day).

Comment: It sounds like you should construct the 1st of the month as a LocalDate, then if that isn't a Monday, call `date = date.Previous(IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);`. That gets you the first element of the array. The rest is just a matter of repeatedly adding a day and taking the day number...

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling generous, try this, but note that in your question your array dimensions were backwards IMHO ...

```
        // Inputs
        int year = 2016;
        int month = 9;
        int numberOfWeeksToList = 5;

        // Create a datetime object for the first day of the month you're interested in
        var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

        // Get the day of the week for that date
        var dowForFirstOfMonth = (int) firstOfMonth.DayOfWeek;

        // You want to start the week on a Monday, so get the difference between the days
        // -- note the DayOfWeek property has 0 for Sunday, so we add a week and mod to handle
        //    negative differences
        var numberOfDaysFromPreviousMonthToInclude = (dowForFirstOfMonth - (int) DayOfWeek.Monday + 7)%7;

        // The first date to include is the first date of the month subtract the number of days
        // from the previous month to include, i.e. stepping back in time a few days
        var firstDateToList = firstOfMonth.AddDays(-numberOfDaysFromPreviousMonthToInclude);

        // Create a 2D array, with the minor dimension representing one week
        int[,] daysInMonthByWeek = new int[numberOfWeeksToList, 7];

        // Now loop through each week's worth of dates, up to the configured number of weeks ...
        int dateIndex = 0;
        for (int weekIndex = 0; weekIndex < numberOfWeeksToList; ++weekIndex)
        {
            for (int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < 7; ++dayIndex)
            {
                // Add the date index to the previously-computed first date to be displayed, and
                // include the 'Day' component of the date
                daysInMonthByWeek[weekIndex, dayIndex] = firstDateToList.AddDays(dateIndex).Day;
                ++dateIndex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: so my return should be :
`return daysInMonthByWeek;`

Comment: Still getting repeatedly 29
[Output screenshot](http://imgur.com/jEp63jy)

Comment: Yes, if you want to return anything then return daysInMonthByWeek.  What input values are you providing as it is working just fine for me.  You've typed something in wrong.

Comment: Sorry you are right, works perfectly!
Just one quick question, is it possible to convert the daysInMonthByWeek in strings?
`daysInMonthByWeek.ToString()`

Comment: Calling ToString() on an array will just output whatever the build-in ToString() method for that type does.  You would be better to have a second method that returned the string in the format that you want, e.g. `string GetFormattedDaysInMonth(int[,] daysInMonthByWeek)`

Comment: I tried to use this way but no sucess:
`public static string MonthDayText
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Join("", daysInMonthByWeek);
            }
        }`

Comment: Ok this is starting to diverge in to a different question that you should post separately.  Make sure you are clear what you actually want though - do you want a set of strings, i.e. one per week, or just one string?  Do you want them separating by spaces?  Etc, etc.  But as I say, this should be posted separately.

Comment: Problem solved! I converted my 35 int values to strings and put them in a List.